# Functional programming in Scala: how to unit test function composition

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm reading the book "Functional Programming in Scala" and I'm writing unit tests to check the implementation of the exercises.

One thing I'm not sure I understood is how to unit test exercises using function composition and passage of state, explained in the chapter 6 of the book.

For example one exercise (ex. 6.8 of the book) is related to the implementation of the function **flatMap** using passage of state, below the solution:

```
def flatMap[A, B](f: Rand[A])(g: A => Rand[B]): Rand[B] = {
  rng => {
    val (a, rng2) = f(rng)
    g(a)(rng2)
  }
}
```

Now, I do understand the implementation of the solution, but I'm not able to figure out how to write a unit test for it.
In detail, I understand how to pass Rand[A] as parameter for the function **f**, but I don't know how to build the function **g**, that should return a Rand[B].

Has anyone came up with a solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is you question about testing the solution or using the solution?

Comment: Hi @pedrofurla: testing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement a function `A => Rand[B]` that takes an `A` and returns a `Rand[B]`, you just need

1. A way to create a `Rand[B]` (where this is defined as an alias for `RNG => (B,RNG)`). You can do it explicitly (by creating an `RNG` and defining the function) or you can use other functions that return a `Rand[B]` (such as `unit`, `map`, ...).
2. A logic to produce a `B` from an `A`

   ```
   val g: RNG = // ...
   val ra: Rand[Int] = // ... you know how to build it, you say
   val rb: Rand[String] = flatMap(ra)(n => unit("hello")) // E.g., you ignore 'n'
   rb(g)._1 shouldEqual "hello"
   ```